# How to properly write code in order to send a php muliple array to JSON?

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax

I need to perform a task which consists in sending a php multiple array to JSON, but it doesn't work and i don't know if i am missing something!

Since it is 2 days that i am having this trouble i decided asking here, because i haven't found nothing much on how properly write the code, especially for the php part.

How can i improve this code in order to make it work? Is the php part done correctly? What function should i use, if there are, to make everything going right?

AJAX call:

```
    function ajaxcall(ID)
    {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'visualize.php',
          data: {id: ID},
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
            for (i=0; i<data.length; i++)
            {
              var state = data.i.state;
              var comment = data.i.comment;
              var date1 = data.i.date1;
              var date2 = data.i.date2;
              $('.comments').append("<b> state: </b> " + state + "<br>"
                                + "<b> comment: </b> " + comment + " <br>"
                                + "<b> date1: </b> " + date1 + " <br>"
                                + "<b> date2: </b> " + date2 + " <br>");
            }
          },
          error : function(err, req) {
            alert("SOMEWHING WENT BAD");
          }
      });
    }
```

visualize.php

```
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Cstate WHERE cod = $id ORDER BY Cod2 ASC");
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $i=0;
    while($i < $num)
    {
      $arr2 = array("$i" => array('state' => mysql_result($result, $i, "StateC"),
                        'comment' => mysql_result($result, $i, "Comment"),
                        'date1' =>  mysql_result($result, $i, "Date1");,
                        'date2' => mysql_result($result, $i, "Date2");));
      $i++;
    }
    echo json_encode($arr2);
```

EDIT: if i print the "arr2" in my browser it works as a proper JSON string.

Comment: If possible, you should attempt to avoid using [mysql_](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) PHP functions. They are deprecated and vulnerable. Instead you might want to try using [mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions instead.

Comment: This should not affect operation, but why is the AJAX call method `POST`? You need to "get" data from the server, based on a given `id`, so it would be better to use method `GET`.

Comment: I forgot a part: $id = $_POST['id'];
But id is actually ok.

Comment: In the javascript, the line with `$('comments').html(...)` will overwrite the html in each iteration. Perhaps you want to append each `data` with e.g. `$('.comments').append("<b> state: </b> " + state + "<br>" + ... );`

Comment: Oh yes, thank you, that was written with the append function actually but for a debug, just one line would have been ok. The fact is that i don't get no lines at all! (but i will give an edit since it's actually wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be you are making life rather more complicated that you need to.

With a simple change to your query, to return just what you want and to rename the column names at the same time (not sure why thats necessary but) you could do this. Then with the use of `mysql_fetch_assoc()` you get all you want without all that complex result jiggling.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT StateC as state, Comment as comment,
                              Date1 as date1, Date2 as date2 
                       FROM Cstate 
                       WHERE cod = $id ORDER BY Cod2 ASC");

$arr2 = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
      $arr2[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($arr2);
```

This will create an `arr2` containing multiple rows which are also arrays.

I personally would go for sending an array of objects as objects are a breeze to use when the data gets to the javascript.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT StateC as state, Comment as comment,
                              Date1 as date1, Date2 as date2 
                       FROM Cstate 
                       WHERE cod = $id ORDER BY Cod2 ASC");

$arr2 = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
      $arr2[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($arr2);
```

Now using the `mysql_fetch_object()` approach, your javascript for the `success` processing could also be simplified to :-

```
success: function(data) {
    var temp = '';
    for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        temp += "<b> state: </b> " + data[i].state + "<br>"
             + "<b> comment: </b> " + data[i].comment + " <br>"
             + "<b> date1: </b> " + data[i].date1 + " <br>"
             + "<b> date2: </b> " + data[i].date2 + " <br>";
    }
    $('.comments').html(temp);
 },
```

NOTE: This also fixes the overwriting of the `$('.comments').html` in your original javascript code, which would have only shown the data from the last array occurance.

Comment: I will try! I know that there was a better solution, knowing how to code properly. That's what i was looking for anyway, and this code inspired me, there is a lot to learn there :)

Comment: If you are just starting out, try and avoid using the `mysql_` database access extension, it wont exist in PHP7! Unless the project is locked into `mysql_` calls you would be well advised to learn the `PDO` or `MYSQLI_` extensions instead.

Comment: Yes, i am kinda "starting", it's just 3 months that i started developing web applications and there is a lot of code that need to be revised, since my skills grew up fast :) Anyway i was having an issue with your code, maybe it was because the "var" was initalized in the for loop, i put that outside, left just "temp" in it and it is working (i still have a problem with the "undefined" at the very start but hey, it's not a big deal now!) Thank you very much!

Comment: Well spotted, I have changed the answer to fix the `var` issue. What is `undefined`?

Comment: Well, you see, i think that you do a "concatenation", is called so? And then, if you inizialize a variable without any value js gives a special value called "unidentifed", that, in combination with the automatic change of variable type (in this case, from ? to string) it prints "unidentifed" before the rest of my html code. But it's an issue that could be resolved defining the var temp,  "var temp = ""; ", in fact is gone :)

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Variables should always be initialized for security

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your results in the loop:

```
  $arr2 = array("$i" => array('state' => mysql_result($result, $i, "StateC"),
                    'comment' => mysql_result($result, $i, "Comment"),
                    'date1' =>  mysql_result($result, $i, "Date1");,
                    'date2' => mysql_result($result, $i, "Date2");));
```

Now you will generate a new array with 1 key - value pair each time so you will end up with information from only the last row that was found.

What you want, is something like (I also removed some syntax errors in the array itself...):

```
$arr2 = array();
while($i < $num)
{
  // or $arr2["$i"] depending if you want numerical or string keys
  $arr2[$i] = array('state' => mysql_result($result, $i, "StateC"),
                    'comment' => mysql_result($result, $i, "Comment"),
                    'date1' =>  mysql_result($result, $i, "Date1"),
                    'date2' => mysql_result($result, $i, "Date2"));
```

And you should use PDO or mysqli in combination with prepared statements to avoid <strike>potential</strike> sql injection problems.

Comment: Well, at first i wrote this code! I needed numbers since as you can see i use numbers in my AJAX call. Anyway it isn't still working. Maybe something is wrong in the AJAX call.

Comment: @LoneWolf You don't even need the numbers, php will do that automcatically if you use `$arr[] = ...`

Answer (score 0):

For associative arrays or arrays with missing indicies JSON always encodes them as a javascript object.  When decoded by json_decode they will be converted to PHP objects.

If you want them to be decoded as arrays you need to call json_decode with the correct parameters.

```
json_decode ( $json, TRUE );
```

All of this is in the PHP manual for json_decode.

Answer (score 0):

```
     $i=1; use this because on  `json_encode($arr2);` throw a error sometime 

 $arr2[$i] = array('state' => mysql_result($result, $i, "StateC"),
                    'comment' => mysql_result($result, $i, "Comment"),
                    'date1' =>  mysql_result($result, $i, "Date1"),
                    'date2' => mysql_result($result, $i, "Date");
```